# Generating PDF in Swift from HTML Template

Tags: html, ios, css, swift

I am trying to implement a PDF generator for my iOS application from a HTML-CSS template.

It successfully generates it, although for some reason, it doesn't cut properly at the end of the page properly. [Screenshot from PDF export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciTPB.png)

I already tried;

- [page-break](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)
- [@media print](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

My PrintRenderer Swift class is;

```
class CustomPrintPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer {

    let A4PageWidth: CGFloat = 595.2
    let A4PageHeight: CGFloat = 841.8

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let pageFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: A4PageWidth, height: A4PageHeight)

        self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: pageFrame), forKey: "paperRect")
        self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: pageFrame.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10)), forKey: "printableRect")

    }
}
```

And my HTML template file's *media-print* section is;

```
        @media print {
            height: auto;

            #skills {
                padding-top: 5mm;
                display: block;
                page-break-before: auto;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: auto;

                background-color: red;
            }

            #lesson {
                height: 100%;
                display: block;

                page-break-before: avoid;
                page-break-inside: always;
                page-break-after: auto;
                border-top: none;
                background-color: green;
            }

            #drivingTests {
                display: block;

                page-break-before: auto;
                page-break-inside: auto;
                page-break-after: avoid;
                border-top: none;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            .wrapTable:not(.innerWrapTable) {
                display: block;
                page-break-before: auto;
                page-break-inside: auto;
                page-break-after: auto;
            }


        }
```

Body of the HTML template file is;

```
<body>
    <div id="contentWrap">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Ausbildungskarte</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Kat. #category#</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>#headerLogo#</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </header>

        <!-- Personal Information -->
        <table id="personalInformation" class="wrapTable">
            <tr>
                <th class="headers">Persönliche Informationen</th>
            </tr>

                #personalInformationItems#
        </table>

        <!-- Skills -->
        <table id="skills" class="wrapTable">
            <tr>
                <th class="headers">Skills</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="wrapTable innerWrapTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="skillColumnItem">#skillSectionLeftItem#</td>
                            <td class="skillColumnItem">#skillSectionMiddleItem#</td>
                            <td class="skillColumnItem">#skillSectionRightItem#</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- Lesson -->
        <table id="lesson" class="wrapTable">
            <tr>
                <th class="headers">Lessons</th>
            </tr>

                #lessonItems#
        </table>

        <!-- Driving Tests -->
        <table id="drivingTests" class="wrapTable">
            <tr>
                <th class="headers">Driving Tests</th>
            </tr>

                #drivingTestItems#
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

If necessary, I can share the full HTML file, which is around 300 lines.

Any advice or error correction is appreciated.